# Database query load balancing

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, load-balancing

I have several instances of an application running the same query against several SQL Server databases. There is a manual load balancing mechanism in place: each instance uses an algorithm to asimmetrically decide which server to query at a given time.

The processing time of the query, and thus the resource consumption on the server, varies greatly depending on the input parameters, which are different each time that the queries are fired.

The current implementation of the balancing algorithm causes, from time to time, one of the severs ending up as the target of several "long/heavy" queries, while the other servers are left underused.

As I know beforehand if a query is a heavy one, how could I improve the algorithm to prevent that server overload?

Right now each application instance decides how to do the balancing independently of each other, so I guess I should share the load information between all instances, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Ops! Downvoted... what i did wrong?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: You told us literally nothing about your problem other than "*I am doing load-balancing. How can I make it better?*"

Comment: Thanks @RBarryYoung, I've rewritten to be more clear on my problem.

Comment: Probably not really important, but which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's MS SQL Server (I know because the OP is a coworker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering myself:

Intially I was looking for something able to implement diffrent types of balancing   http://www.peplink.com/technology/load-balancing-algorithms/ ,
even I have found a nice article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3338/NET-Dynamic-Software-Load-Balancing

Finally I have decide to keep it simple, as I know about the *weight* of the request I'll just take the server with less charge.
**EDIT:** Added based weight to each server. Now the balancing is done by weight and load. Code can be tested in [linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/)

```
// Define other methods and classes here
public class LoadBalancer{

    class Server{
        public long Weight{ get; set;}
        public long Load{ get; set;}
        public string ConnectionString{ get; set;}
        public long RequestCount;
        // Return a weight based on the Load
        public long CurrentWeight {
            get{ 
                var w = Weight - Load; 
                return w <= 0 ? 1: w;
            }
        }
    }
    List<Server> Servers;
    public LoadBalancer(){
        Servers = new List<Server>();
    }

    public void AddServer(long weight, string connection){
        lock(Servers)
            Servers.Add(new UserQuery.LoadBalancer.Server(){ ConnectionString = connection, Weight = weight });
    }
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    // Returns server with less load
    public string GetServer(int expectedLoad){
        var hit = rnd.Next(0, (int)Servers.Sum(s => s.CurrentWeight));
        long acc = 0;
        foreach(var server in Servers){
            if(hit < server.CurrentWeight + acc){
                // Update load
                lock(server){
                    server.Load += expectedLoad;
                    server.RequestCount++;
                }
                return server.ConnectionString; 
            }
            acc += server.CurrentWeight;
        }
        throw new Exception("No servers available");
    }

    public void ReleaseServer(string conn, int expectedLoad){
        var server = Servers.First(s => s.ConnectionString == conn);
        // Update load
        lock(server){
            server.Load -= expectedLoad;
            server.RequestCount--;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Dump(){
        return Servers.Select(s => string.Format("Server: {0}, Requests: {1}, Weight: {2}, CurrentWeight: {3}",
            s.ConnectionString, s.RequestCount, s.Weight, s.CurrentWeight));
    }

}

void Main()
{
    var balancer = new LoadBalancer();
    // Add servers
    balancer.AddServer(100, "Server1");
    balancer.AddServer(100, "Server2");
    balancer.AddServer(800, "Server3");
    balancer.AddServer(200, "Server4");
    balancer.AddServer(1000, "Server5");

    var rnd = new Random();
    var servers = new List<dynamic>();
    Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
    .All(i => {
        var load = rnd.Next(1, 10);
        var server = balancer.GetServer(load);
        servers.Add(new {Server = server, Load = load});
        if(i % 10 == 0){
            balancer.Dump().Dump();
            // Remove some load
            var items = rnd.Next(0, servers.Count);
            servers.Take(items)
            .All(s => {
                balancer.ReleaseServer(s.Server, s.Load);
                return true;
            });
            servers = servers.Skip(items).ToList();
        }
        return true;
    });
    servers.All(s => {
                balancer.ReleaseServer(s.Server, s.Load);
                return true;
            });
    balancer.Dump().Dump();
}
```